# function "openfile" returning workbook ends with run-time error '91'

Tags: vba, excel

I want to open and refer to a workbook via the function below. Only the function produces the run-time error '91': object variable or with block variable not set just before jumping back into the main code.
When I put the exact code (just not as function) into my main code it works perfectly.
But I don't want to have the whole function in my main code because I think it's unnecessary and ugly.
Maybe someone can help me make my code nicer and better comprehensible!
Thank you already!

This is the relevant part of my main sub:

```
Sub main_sub()
    Dim WBtest As Workbook
    Dim WBpath As String

    WBpath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Range("A6").Value    'read path
    WBtest = openfile(WBpath) 'I call my function here
End Sub
```

This is the function that produces the error
The function is supposed to return the (newly) opened workbook

```
Public Function openfile(path As String) As Workbook    'path is fullpath
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim alreadyopen As Boolean

    For Each wb In Workbooks     'loop over all Workbooks
        If wb.FullName = path Then 'check if file is already open
            alreadyopen = True
            Set openfile = wb
        End If
    Next wb
    If alreadyopen = False Then
        'file not yet opened --> open it
        Set openfile = Workbooks.Open(path)
    End If
    'MsgBox openfile.name 'this returns the right name
End Function
```

When I write all of it in my main sub it works (but is ugly, so I don't want it there!)
This works:

```
Sub main_sub()
    Dim WBtest As Workbook
    Dim WBpath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook 'for loop
    Dim alreadyopen As Boolean

    WBpath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Range("A6").Value    'read path

    For Each wb In Workbooks     'loop over all Workbooks
        If wb.FullName = WBpath Then
            alreadyopen = True
            Set WBtest = wb
        End If
    Next wb
    If alreadyopen = False Then
        'file not yet opened --> open it
        Set WBtest = Workbooks.Open(WBpath)
    End If
 End Sub
```

I have a similar problem later in my code, where I want to have a function return a workbook, too. So this seems to be the problem.
How does a function return a workbook?
I have found similar functions returnins worksheets. Those work. Why not with workbooks?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different between both approaches is that, in the first one, you are forgetting the `Set` bit. Thus, solution:

```
Set WBtest = openfile(WBpath) 'I call my function here
```

Comment: ok, this was dumb, I was pretty sure I checked that, but I guess I didn't... Thanks, it works now!

Comment: @grinsbaeckchen you did it inside of the function and (I guess) that assumed that it was enough; but the new assignation WBTest = returned variable needs it too. This is kind of dumb error everyone makes (at least, once) :)

Comment: This may be an old answer, but thank you kind sir, you've saved me from an hour of facepalming!

Comment: @DaMachk You are welcome, polite gentleman. It is indeed an old one, not as old as using Set though (I guess that you are new to VBA).